# Interface Builder to follow full-screen and orientation rules?

Tags: xcode

I have an app that uses the "Status bar is initially hidden" property in the plist file to create a full-screen presentation. Works fine.

In the viewController, the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method returns YES if `interfaceOrientation` != portrait or portraitUpsideDown, thus, my app works in landscapeLeft and landscapeRight. And it does so fine.

But, when I enter into Xcode 4's interface builder, my viewController and custom views all show the status bar, and are always in Portrait mode.

This makes it difficult to work with custom views that are 1024x768 fullscreen. I can never entirely tell easily if what I am seeing is in fact the full view PLUS the status bar, or if my custom view is showing behind the status bar, etc. And, particularly strange, my custom view retains an x,y coordinate system in Portrait mode, even when my app is in landscape. Usually, x and y switch places when I rotate a view controller, but this doesn't seem to work on a custom view.

So in short, how can I get my views and controller and interface builder to all be landscape-friendly, with no status bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the IB, click on your main view and open the Attributes window (command-1). Under "Simulated User Interface Elements",  change "Orientation" to "Landscape" and "Status Bar" to "Unspecified".

Remember, the IB doesn't read all of your code, so it doesn't know what you've done programmatically.